# Load XML with script

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to load an XML file with this script, but when I run the code and I press the "Button" I get this message:

> Blocked request from another source : the same origin policy prevents
>   the remote resource read https://therouteofmyxml.xml ( reason :
>   missing CORS ' Allow- Access- Control- header Origin ' ).

Is it because I have any extension or plugin on my browser? Thanks!!

```
<script>
        function loadXMLDoc(){
            xmlhttp=null;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (xmlhttp!=null){
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
                        var txt="";
                        x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("offer");
                        for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
                            txt=txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                        }
                        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","https://therouteofmy.xml",true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
            else{
                alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Mis Ofertas</button>
```

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with extensions or plugins. Loading XML from another domain is something you're generally not supposed to do for security reasons. Do some research on the same origin policy for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML with the script is loaded from `http://example.com/` it can only load XML from that same origin, e.g. a file `http://example.com/file.xml`, but not from a different origin like `http://example.org/`, unless the other site cooperates and allows such requests explicitly. See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing for details.